# IndexOutOfRangeException in multidimensional Arrays

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have enclosed the code below, I was getting IndexOutOfRangeException not handled in Part A, then I tried Try-catch as below but now I am getting

**"A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in app.exe
   at app.Form6.ZMove(String s1, String s2) in C:\Users\Rahul Taneja\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\app\app\Form6.cs:line 136"**

in stack trace

can any one tell me why it is happening and what could be the solution?

```
public void ZMove(string s1, string s2)
        {
            //Move 2-1-4-3
            int j = Int32.Parse(s1);
            int k = Int32.Parse(s2);
            for (int l = 0; l < k; l++)
            {
                try
                {
                    swap(array[2][j], array[1][j]); ///Part A
                    swap(array[1][j], array[4][j]);
                    swap(array[4][j], array[3][j]);
                    swap(array[3][j], array[2][j]);
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace);
                    //throw;
                }
            }
        }

        private void swap(char[] p1, char[] p2)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            int l = p1.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            {
                char temp = p1[i];
                p1[i] = p2[i];
                p2[i] = temp;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  What is the shape of the array on that line?  The easy answer is that one of the array indexes being used in the code doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: I mentioned, it is Part A, array is a 3D Array

Comment: And what's the shape of the `array` value when the exception is thrown?  And the value of `j`?  Either the first dimension of the array doesn't have an index of 2, or 1, or the second dimension doesn't have an index of `j`.

Comment: Note that you are using jagged arrays, which are similar, but not identical to multidimensional arrays.

Comment: array is 6*N*N, where N is given by the user, it is stored somewhere and, I got this value by the function(in string format), then I casted this string and saved the value in variable j. For exception I have shown the StackTrace

Comment: @RahulTaneja: Yes, you've shown the stack trace.  But you _haven't_ shown the run-time values which are causing the exception.  Clearly you're accessing an array index that isn't there.  At _runtime_, what is the _actual_ shape of the `array` variable (N is not a number) and what is the _actual_ value of `j` (what did the user enter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 12 different accesses of arrays that could be the problem and you're not letting us see how the arrays get created. No reasonable person can help you with your specific problem,

So instead I'll try and answer this question

**How do I debug an `IndexOutOfRangeException`?**

- In Visual Studio open the Exceptions Window
- Expand the Common Language Runtime Exceptions Window
- Expand the System node
- Check the Thrown checkbox for System.IndexOutOfRangeException

When the exception occurs your debugger will break. Now inspect the variables via watch, tooltips, command or immediate windows. I'm sure you'll quickly find exactly what the problem is.

[image]

Note: You can access the Exceptions window via

- Menu item Debug -> Exceptions
- Keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+E</kbd>
- Keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+D,E</kbd>
- The Command Window via `>Debug.Exceptions`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the strings s1,s2, are the absolute position and you actually should do:

```
int j = Int32.Parse(s1) -1;

int k = Int32.Parse(s2) -1;
```